# what is the difference between [ EmailPasswordAuthProvider, EmailAuthProvider ]

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting confused after lot of search and I want to get credentials.

I found 2 different services doing same thing.

[ **EmailPasswordAuthProvider**,  **EmailAuthProvider**    ]

In those firebase docs

[1-EmailPasswordAuthProvider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth)

[2-EmailAuthProvider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking)

and code was

`var credential = firebase.auth.EmailPasswordAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);`

So what is difference and why  ***EmailPasswordAuthProvider*** is not defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that's a typo in the documentation. It should be `EmailAuthProvider`

`firebase.auth.EmailPasswordAuthProvider` is undefined in the latest version of the SDK (3.6.1 as well as in older versions of v3)

Comment: Looks like a typo indeed. I submitted a patch to the web site. Thanks for the report!